# VM Host Windows VNC Client isn't finding VM Guest Linux VNC Server ... why?

Tags: linux, vnc, remote-access

I have a Debian 6 guest (VirtualBox) sitting on a Windows XP host. In Debian I've configured tightvncserver. In Windows XP I've installed TightVNC client.

On Debian I do the following:

```
$ sudo netstat -nr

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0

$ tightvncserver

New 'X' desktop is rand-office:1

Starting applications specified in /home/randm/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/randm/.vnc/rand-office:1.log
```

On the Windows host, in the TightVNC Viewer, I try to connect to 10.0.2.2:5900.

After ~20 seconds, it tells me that it failed to connect to server 10.0.2.2.

Question: what am I doing wrong?

===EDIT===

I'm able to connect via PuTTY from the Windows Host. So some amount of connectivity is working.

Comment: Most probably, theLinux Vm is connect to Windows Host using NAT. Try changing it to bridged.

Comment: It was on NAT. I changed to bridged. The IP address changed ... trying the new IP address (@ port 5900) failed to connect in 1 second instead of 20.

Comment: Which are the firewall settings for the guest machine?. If you do a "netstat -lp" on Debian, do you see vnc listening on tcp/5900?

Comment: Bingo ... Xtightvnc @ *:5901 instead of *:5900. Now I just have to figure out how to secure all this stuff. Thanks much. Should I just delete this question or close it so that the trail is here?